# Blank screen upon launch Unity 3D Android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have developed a game which I was testing on a an emulator after I create APK. Earlier it has no problems in running.

The problem with the game is, upon launching it shows a blank screen. The resolution is set properly.

In moto g if set graphics level as opengl 2.0 then it will run. But in note 3 it will be a blank screen. In note3 I need set as automatic graphics level. But this causes blank screen in moto g.

I don't know what is happening there?

Mine is moto g and my client's is note 3.

Can you please help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest Unity 4.6.1p2. If the problem still occurs please give more info about your unity version and logcat messages.